# why use yosemite bootable usb installer when you can use recovery HD for clean install?

Tags: macos, usb, install, recovery

i just re-installed Yosemite from Recovery HD. Performed a clean install as i erased my HD from Recovery HD before installing the software.

Yosemite is being downloaded since a few hours but it would be the same with the USB Installer as Recovery HD is an Installer too.

So in both cases you need internet.
Am i right or wrong?

Comment: Well - both need internet, but one needs it right this minute or you're stuck, the other is at your leisure.

Answer (score 1):

A bootable drive saves the entire OS X installer locally. If your current reinstall were happening from a bootable drive, the "downloading Yosemite" step would be nonexistent because everything's already there.

As in, you're wrong. The specific benefit of a bootable drive is the ability to reinstall OS X without needing to download it on the spot. (Of course, first you needed to have downloaded the OS X installer and run through [the bootable drive-making procedure](http://www.macworld.com/article/2367748/how-to-make-a-bootable-os-x-10-10-yosemite-install-drive.html) at some point beforehand, but the point is that once you've done that one download, you've got it for whenever you need it.)

Comment: Yup - I keep one ready on a USB key for that 'just in case' moment.